# swipe down gesture on MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

My application begins with a movie, and I am trying to swipe down or slide down to continue the movie but I don't know why the gesture doesn't work, I tried to use:

```
[player view].userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

```
-(void) swiped: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender {

    NSLog(@"SLIDE DOWN");
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sahar3" ofType:@"mov"];

    player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

    player.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedPlaying:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[player moviePlayer]];

    player.moviePlayer.repeatMode = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"lunched");
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped:)];
    swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     NSLog(@"lunched");
     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(swiped:)];
     swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
//add the following line in your application
     [self.view addgesturerecognizer:swipe];
}
```

i think you forgot to add  outlet on which you want to apply swipe gesture recognizer

Comment: One problem after switching movies there is blinking between them how can I fix it ?

Comment: i didn't get you can you explain little bit more

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing the – gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: delegate method and return YES.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: did you set the gesture recognizer's delegate to the object you implemented the method in?